# Getting Access_Denied response when using Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn.LinkedInAuthenticationProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, linkedin-api

I'm playing with `Owin.Security.Providers` project to allow my MVC 5 app sign in with various social networks. I created an app in LinkedIn and set its scope to `r_emailaddress` and `r_basicprofile`. When I try to sign in with LinkedIn accout, I get `/Login/SigninRedirect?error=access_denied` on my return URL. Though my `CallbackPath` which is set to `/signin-redirect` URL has `code` and `state` attributes. In Fiddler it looks like this: `/signin-redirect?code=<code_id>&state=<state_id>`. 
Anyone has any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
protected virtual void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var linkedInAuthOptions = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = <client_id>,
            ClientSecret = <client_secret>,
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-redirect")
        };
        app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(linkedInAuthOptions);
    }
```

In my Login controller I handle sign in and the redirect similar to VS2013 example:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        var redirectUrl = "/Login/SigninRedirect";
        redirectUrl += string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? "" : "?redirectUrl=" + returnUrl;

        return new ChallengeResult(provider, redirectUrl);
    }

    // Redirects from successful social signin to a speccified URL.
    public ActionResult SigninRedirect(string redirectUrl)
    {
        var redirect = string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUrl) ? "/" : redirectUrl;

        ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo();
        // loginInfo is null when trying to sign in with LinkedIn
        // works fine for Twitter though
        if (loginInfo != null)
        {
            var authResult = AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie).Result;
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            var claims = authResult.Identity.Claims.ToList();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider));

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, claimsIdentity);
        }
        return new RedirectResult(redirect);
    }

    #region Helpers

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUrl, string userId = null)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUrl = redirectUrl;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() {RedirectUri = RedirectUrl};
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The same code works fine when I try to sign in with Twitter account.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. The problem was that I registered the same `CallbackPath` (`/signin-redirect`) for both Twitter and LinkedIn providers. Like this:

```
        var twitterAuthOptions = new TwitterAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ConsumerKey = <consumerKey>,
            ConsumerSecret = <consumerSecret>,
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-redirect")
        };
        app.UseTwitterAuthentication(twitterAuthOptions);

        var linkedInAuthOptions = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = <clientId>,
            ClientSecret = <clientSecret>,
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-redirect")
        };
        app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(linkedInAuthOptions);
```

When I set different `CallbackPath`'s, everything started working fine.